# Kubernetes RBAC set subtraction / cluster-admin without capabilities

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, rbac

Is it possible to create a Kubernetes cluster admin without the ability to modify/read certain namespace and its content?

I am talking about subtracting certain permissions from existing role.

thanks.

Comment: Not natively, no. But there is a relatively new (and quickly becoming popular) package that can handle `deny` rules. It's OPA (Open Policy Agent), and it basically acts as a much more fine-grained control RBAC for Kubernetes: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kubernetes-introduction/. It supports `deny` rules and might be a useful stopgap for Kubernetes already missing this functionality

Answer (score 1):

To get the behavior you want you would need a [set subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of cluster-admin role minus the rules that you have defined. [It's not supported in K8s as of this writing.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70387)

If you  need a custom role which has less permissions than a predefined role, it would be more clear to list those permissions rather than to list the inverse of those permissions.